# NAudio - Does a new instance of OffsetSampleProvider have to be created for each playback

Tags: audio, naudio

As explained [here](http://markheath.net/post/naudio-play-extract), `OffsetSampleProvider` can be used in order to play a specific portion of an audio file. Like this:

```
AudioFileReader AudioReader = new AudioFileReader("x.wav");
OffsetSampleProvider OffsetProvider = New OffsetSampleProvider(AudioReader);

OffsetProvider.SkipOver = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
OffsetProvider.Take = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);

myWaveOut.Init(OffsetProvider);
myWaveOut.Play();
```

The above example will play an audio for 8 seconds, starting at second 5. However, if I want to play it again, it will not play, unless I set the `Position` property of the `AudioFileReader` to 0, and re-create a new instance of `OffsetSampleProvider` from it. So I would like to know if I'm missing something, or this is the way that `OffsetSampleProvider` should be used (and if it does, do I have to free any resources related to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the code for `OffsetSampleProvider` and add a `Reset` method to it. I'd also avoid using `SkipOver` for performance reasons and just set the `CurrentTime` of the `AudioFileReader` to 5 seconds directly before you play.